# fetching data from laravel API to react native app ( created with expo )

Tags: laravel, api, react-native, expo

i created a **react native** app using **expo** and i'm running it on an **android** device with the expo app or USB cable , in addition to a **laravel APi** that i'm using it to test if anything is OK before implementing authentication , the thing is that i'm always getting the error message ( i defined it in the fetch function ) , i said maybe it's because of the URL but when i try it on the web it work fine ! i hope that this explanation is clear ! **i need help to get the data from the laravel api to the react native app !**

***react native :***

the constructor code :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }
```

this is the fetch function  :

```
_onLoginPressed = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/indexp", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);

          Alert.alert("logged");

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('erroc message');
      });
  };
```

the expo is runnig in this adress (LAN): **exp://192.168.1.4:19000**

***laravel :***

in api.php

```
Route::get('indexp','PostsController@indexp');
```

in PostsController :

```
  public function indexp()
    {
        $post = Post::all();

        return response()->json($post);
    }
```

[image]

***if i install android studio and run it on an emulator maybe it will work ?***

Comment: No experience with Expo, but this is probably because of the `127.0.0.1` IP address. It's like using `localhost` - it points to the same host machine. By looking at the Laravel app on computer (browser), it's the same machine so it can find the IP/port combo. But if you view from a different device, `127.0.0.1` will point to _that_ device, where Laravel is not installed.

Comment: do you suggest any solution i should try it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is at the fetch request. You need to access the IP of the API server, in this case the LAN address of your PC (run ifconfig on linux or ipconfig in windows).
Then you have to start your webserver with that IP as host, and set a port if you want, i.e.
**php artisan serve --host 192.168.10.100 --port 8000**, where the IP is the IP of your PC and the port is the one you like.

Then on your fetch request you have to go the **http://192.168.10.100:8000/api/indexp** and get the results from there.
I would recommend not getting the IP and port on each file, but putting them on a config file so if you need to change them you just change in one place

Comment: How do i do the same thing but by passing an id to the laravel API and getting back the response?

Answer (score 0):

Like "julix" said, the problem is in the URL, expo or react native apps does not recognize http request localhost instead use your ip address, with laravel set manually the server's host from the default 127.0.0.1 to 192.168.0.1(YOUR IP ADDRESS) with a port of 8000